# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Firebase'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to react and i have been trying to initialize firebase into my react app.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';



 var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCvSb1gFiUYMJA4SbsKlJvhFwJ8IFjSwkg",
    authDomain: "raya-feedback.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://raya-feedback-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    projectId: "raya-feedback",
    storageBucket: "raya-feedback.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "575830594611",
    appId: "1:575830594611:web:930556a8f2ccf9bf733f46"
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export {firebase};
;
```

This is my Firebase.js file that I am trying to import into my Body.js file and I have been getting this error "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Firebase.js'".

This is my file structure:[image]

This is how I am importing it in the Body.js file

```
import firebase from './Firebase';
```

I am kind of lost and I have been trying to initialize in a multitude of different ways I see on Youtube and I am still stuck on this error.

Comment: so body is inside components? then u should use `../Firebase`

Comment: Tried all of them ../, ../../ , ./../ all do not work. I do not understand what is going on. Even the terminal suggests “./Firebase” and it still doesn’t work.

Comment: I edited the code and added the file structure. Still the same error.

Comment: "firebase": "^9.9.4"

Comment: This is very hard to keep track of since you keep changing coding styles and imports. With your [current revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/73601469/4), you should be using `import { firebase } from "../Firebase"` in `Body.js` since you don't have a default export and the `Firebase.js` file is in the relative parent directory to `Body.js`

Comment: This finally worked thank you so much for your help and sorry to bother you with this. If it is not difficult work can you post the v9 version of this code?

Comment: _"Can you post the v9 version of this code?"_... why when [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add-sdks-initialize) is actually very good

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your folder structure **Firebase.js** is inside **src** and your trying to process Firebase.js from src/body, since Firebase.js doesn't exist in body you are getting this error, you have to use

> import { firebase } from '../Firebase';

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

So you may be encountering this error because there is some other error in your Firebase.js file.

I noticed in your code snippet above `getauth` needs to actually be `getAuth`

./ means the current directory,
../ means the parent directory (previous one)
../../ means the parent of the parent and so on.

you need to use `../Firebase`